# How can i iterate all member of a dto in java?

Tags: java

I have a problem about basic java. I have a class which it has lots of bigdecimal members.
I want to iterate all members of this class via a loop. Is there any way for this?

```
public class LargeDTO extends CoreDTO {
    private BigDecimal price1;
    private BigDecimal price2;
    private BigDecimal price3;
    private BigDecimal price4;
    private BigDecimal price5;
    private BigDecimal price6;
    ...
    // getter & setter
}

public class UseLoop{
    LargeDTO largeDTO = fillLatgeDTO();
    BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.Zero;
    // Is it possible ?
    for(each member of largeDTO){
         total = total.add(largeDTO.getCurrentMember()); // price1, price2...
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use a collection example: `List<BigDecimal>` or via reflection

Comment: Why are you storing a list of prices in that manner instead of using a container like a `List`?

Comment: This is a DB table and every price is a colomn of the table. So hibernate generate this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to Reflection API, you can take a look at [BeanInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) class from ***java.beans*** package or the [BeanMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanMap.html) class from the [Apache BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) project.

Using **BeanInfo**

```
for (PropertyDescriptor propDesc :
             Introspector.getBeanInfo(LargeDTO.class).getProperyDescriptors()) {
     total = total.add((BigDecimal) propDesc.getReadMethod().invoke(largeDTO));
}
```

Using **BeanMap**

```
for (Object price : new BeanMap(largeDTO).valueIterator()) {
     total = total.add((BigDecimal) price);
}
```

*Java Doc links to :*

[Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html), [PropertyDescriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html)

Comment: Thank you, BeanInfo is very useful. Also, i can get property name like this propDesc.getName(); // price1...

Comment: @YücelCeylan Glad to be of help. +1 to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Class#getDeclaredFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29)

```
Field[] fields = LargeDTO.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

Or change your current design to have a `List<BigDecimal> prices` instead of having 6 fields of the same type.

```
public class LargeDTO extends CoreDTO {
    private List<BigDecimal> prices;

    public LargeDTO() {
        prices = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
    }

    //getter and setter for your prices
}

//in client class...
LargeDTO largeDTO = new LargeDTO();
//fill the data...
for(BigDecimal price : largeDTO.getPrices()) {
    //do what you want/need...
}
```

Comment: Which import should i choose? And how can i cast back field to bigdecimal?

Comment: @YücelCeylan for `Field` class, none. For `List` and `ArrayList`, use `java.util.List` and `java.util.ArrayList` or `java.util.*`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java reflection: `Class.getDeclaredFields()` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) and inspecting the resulting array of fields.

Comment: `getfields` won't retrieve private fields.

Answer (score 1):

store the big decimals in a list or map instead. Or use reflection, but that would make things needlessly complex imho.

Comment: Yeah Map<String, BigDecimal> seems like the most sensible solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using another data structure in the first place, that is, if the prices are somehow related you could store them in an array and iterate over that. Or you could try something like

```
for (BigDecimal number:new BigDecimal[]{largeDto.getPrice1(), largeDto.getPrice2(), ...}} {...}
```